# How do I make a multiple stacks of controls (columns) scrollable?

Tags: c#, wpf, layout, wpf-controls

so I'm new to using WPF and can't figure out how to make an easy way to have multiple columns of controls that can be added / subtracted easily and still have it scrollable. So for example (my situation), I have two text boxes and a button that need to be added for however many "items" there are. I would want these together in a 3 column layout and all scroll with the same scroll bar.

The best case result would be something like multiple stack panels (in my case 3) filled with an arbitrary amount of controls, that all scroll with the same scroll bar. Since this seems not to work, what do I do instead?

Much appreciated, no matter how inane my questions are you guys are always so helpful.

Comment: No need for [WPF] tag in title.

Answer (score 2):

I think a `WrapPanel` is what you want.

I've found [this tutorial](http://www.wpftutorial.net/WrapPanel.html) which explains its use succinctly. If you set the `Orientation="Vertical"` it should layout as you want.

The [Panels](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754152.aspx) MSDN page gives more information on the different panels and how they should be used. The `WrapPanel` page is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.wrappanel_members.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

```
<ScrollViewer ...>
  <Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" ...>
       ...
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" ...>
       ...
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="2" ...>
       ...
    </StackPanel>
  </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: I'm trying that, but the Grid won't adjust it's height based on how large the stack panels are. Suggestions?

Comment: I have tested it and it works just as you described that you need it to. Maybe you set the height of the Grid? or that of the StackPanels?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried putting all three StackPanels into a `ScrollViewer`?

Comment: I thought you could only put one control in a scrollviewer. Am I mistaken?

Comment: @SirDinosaur - I think you'll need to put them inside another container, but it's certainly possible.

Comment: I just need to find out which container will work best. Worst case scenario I'll do it with a WrapPanel, which is fine, but I'd rather a nicer solution.